# como faço para que quando eu digite "nao", eu retorne para o inicio?

Tags: python, loop, while

```
print('                        BEM-VINDOS A CALCULADORES V1!')
```

cont

1. Relacionar o item

a = int(input('ESCOLHA UMA CONTA\ 1 SOMA\ 2 MENOS/3VEZES\ 4DIVISAO'))
n1 = float(input('primeiro valor'))
n2 = float(input('primeiro valor'))

while conta==1:
soma = n1+n2
print(f'a soma desses numeros foi: {soma}')
break
while conta==2:
menos = n1-n2
print(f'o resultado é {menos}')
break
while conta==3:
multi = n1*n2
print(f'o resultado da multiplicaçaoi é {multi}')
break
while conta==4:
div = n1/n2
print(f'a divisao é {div}')
break
while True or False:
sair = input('deseja sair? [sim] ou [nao]').lower().startswith('sim')
print(sair)
if sair is True:
break

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para tu conseguir voltar do início, caso o usuário deseja fazer uma conta nova, você precisa deixar todo o seu código dentro do "while True:"

Exemplo:

```
while True:
  conta = int(input('ESCOLHA UMA CONTA\ 1 SOMA\ 2 MENOS/3VEZES\ 4DIVISAO'))
  n1 = float(input('primeiro valor')) 
  n2 = float(input('primeiro valor'))
  if conta == 1:
     soma = n1+n2
#Aí você vai colocar as condições que você quer dentro desse while True.
#Você só precisa perguntar para o usuário se ele deseja continuar ou não
  op = input('Deseja continuar? S ou N').upper()                                             
  if op == N:
     break
#Se ele digitar S, automaticamente vai para o início do programa, ou seja, vai perguntar qual operação que ele quer fazer e os números novamente.
```

Espero ter ajudado e entendido!

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).